# how can create message system for a lot of users without much proccess of time in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want design a inside system message for about 10000 user!

Steps seem easy:

1- create a DB table. for example: Message
2- create an user table. for example : user
3- the search Message DB and return all messages to user.

but you know for all 10000 user is too much time  with one table to access messages.

My plan is create a independent table for each user for keep his messages. (not one table for all users)

but after that,Mybe I have 10000 tables in my DB. it is too much and administration is too heavy.

Is there a better way to save messages?

Comment: Just write it (using the "2 table" approach). Add  appropriate indexes, MySQL (even on a relatively mediocre shared system) will have no problem with the query. **Do not create a table-per-user** - SQL multiplicity changes across rows. Creating more tables will make queries harder (have to change the table, can't cross-query), increase SQL resource usage, and can actually *hinder* performance. SQL/RDBMS take care of the "how" so you don't need to.

Comment: (Of course a system on a *much* larger scale - eg. Facebook - needs many extra considerations; but this application with only millions of messages - maybe - won't even stress a basic RDBMS server with sargable queries.)

Comment: The worst thing you can do is create a table for each user. If you do that, please slap yourself for me, I can't reach you.

Answer (score 0):

First , 10000 users is not so much data for mysql. In my system, I have more than 10,000,000 data in one table, and it works well.

Second, whether user and message should be stored in independent tables, this depends on the query. If you make a lot of join, I suggest You store them in one table, But if the join action is not that frequent, you can seperate them.

Comment: If you use "a lot" of joins, and they are slow, I suggest using a real RDMBS database on a real server. Although proper indices solve most 'join problems' :}

Comment: @user2864740 - what is "a real RDBMS database on a real server"?

Comment: @N.B. Any which defers the cost - and suggests of changes in the DB structure - associated 'complex joins' ..